# How to load a video in a MovieClip node

Tags: python, node-editor

How to create a "CompositorNodeMovieClip" node and load a video using the python api in the node editor.

My progress so far...

```
bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True 
nodes = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes 
links = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.links # create the movieclip node 
movieClipNode = nodes.new("CompositorNodeMovieClip") # get the video clip 
videoClip = bpy.data.movieclips.get( videoPath );
```

but videoClip is returned as null..

Comment: My progress so far...bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
nodes = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes
links = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.links

# create the movieclip node
movieClipNode = nodes.new("CompositorNodeMovieClip")

# get the video clip
videoClip = bpy.data.movieclips.get( videoPath ); but videoClip is returned as null..

Comment: In future, please add any extra info into your question and not the comments.

Comment: Thought of keeping the question succinct. Will keep that in mind for the later questions. Thanks for modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using incorrect key , the key is the name of the movie clip

```
#load new movie clip
bpy.data.movieclips.load(clip_path)
#get the new movie clip
movie_clip = bpy.data.movieclips.get(clip_name)
#assign movie clip to the node
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['Movie Clip'].clip = movie_clip
```

Comment: ah.. thanks for pointing out. That fixed it.